# How can I get disabled from input tag?

Tags: java, jsoup

I need to get `disabled` from `<input>` tag.

`HTML` snippet is like:

```
<tr> 
 <td><input type="radio" name="orderChoice" value="1" checked></td> 
 <td>Audi A4, Auto, A/C, $50.00/day</td> 
 <td>user</td> 
 <td>Иванов Иван Иванович 1983-10-03 АВ954326 Святошинським РУ ГУ МВС України у м. Києві 2001-06-05</td> 
 <td>2021-07-10 18:00:00.0</td> 
 <td>2021-07-20 14:00:00.0</td> 
 <td>500.00</td> 
 <td> <input type="checkbox" name="processed" disabled> </td> 
 <td> <input type="checkbox" name="rejected" disabled> </td> 
 <td></td> 
 <td> <input type="checkbox" name="picked" disabled> </td> 
 <td> <input type="checkbox" name="returned" disabled> </td> 
 <td> <input type="checkbox" name="damaged" disabled> </td> 
 <td></td> 
 <td></td> 
 <td> <input type="checkbox" name="paid" disabled> </td> 
</tr>
```

I have the loop which looks like:

```
for (Element tableRow : tableRows) { // iterate over all the table rows (tr elements)
    Element row = tableRows.get(tableRow.elementSiblingIndex());
    String vehicle = row.select("tr > td").get(1).text();
    Element td = row.select("tr > td").get(10); // <td> <input type="checkbox" name="picked" disabled> </td>
    Elements checkbox = td.select("td > input[type=checkbox]"); // <input type="checkbox" name="picked" disabled>
    String picked = checkbox.attr("name"); // picked
    tableList.add(new Table(picked, vehicle));
}
```

and I need to get `disabled` from `input` tag.

Can someone suggest me, please, the way how can I get it without specifying the value explicitly, since `checkbox` can be changed dynamically?

Comment: `checkbox.attributes().hasKey("disabled")`  https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Attributes.html#hasKey(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, @PeterMmm. The problem is `Elements` type doesn't have `attributes()` as method. `Element` has this method, but in my specific case `Element td` will get: `<td> <input type="checkbox" name="picked" disabled> </td>`, so the condition: `td.attributes().hasKey("disabled")` doesn't work as well.

Comment: `Elements` represents multiple `Element`s. You need to specify what `Element` you want (e.g. using `selectFirst()` instead of `select()`).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out it, @dan1st.

Comment: @PeterMmm, thanks, your example was very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@PeterMmmm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67777840/how-can-i-get-disabled-from-input-tag/67779849#comment119802021_67777840) and [@dan1st](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67777840/how-can-i-get-disabled-from-input-tag/67779849#comment119803285_67777840) suggestions, I've solved using `attributes().hasKey("disabled")` and `first()` methods like:

```
for (Element tableRow : tableRows) { //iterate over all the table rows (tr elements)
    Element row = tableRows.get(tableRow.elementSiblingIndex());
    String vehicle = row.select("tr > td").get(1).text();
    Element td = row.select("tr > td").get(10);
    Element input = td.select("td > input[type=checkbox]").first();
    Elements checkbox = td.select("td > input[type=checkbox]");
    String picked = checkbox.attr("name");
    if (input.attributes().hasKey("disabled")) {
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
}
```